# Size mismatch between Python and C struct with default struct alignment/padding

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, data-structures, struct

I have a struct that I'm sending from a C server to a Python client. The C struct is the following one:

```
// Data structure to be sent to python interface
typedef struct {                                        //
    uint32_t componentType;                             // 4
    bool componentId_present;                           // 1 + 3 padding = 4
    uint32_t componentIdType;                           // 4 + 4 padding = 8
    long componentId;                                   // 8
    uint32_t componentConfigUpdate_type;                // 4 + 4 padding = 8
    bool componentConfigUpdate_s1AP_present;            // 1 + 3 padding = 4
    uint32_t componentConfigUpdate_s1AP_size;           // 4
    byte componentConfigUpdate_s1AP[128];               // 128
    bool componentConfigUpdate_x2AP_present;            // 1 + 3 padding = 4
    uint32_t componentConfigUpdate_x2AP_size;           // 4
    byte componentConfigUpdate_x2AP[128];               // 128
} data_E2setupRequest_NodeComponentConfigUpdate_t;      // 256 + 3*8 + 6*4 = 256 + 24 + 24 = 304
```

In Python I compute the size to be received with the following code:

```
import struct
size = struct.calcsize("i?ili?i128s?i128s")             # returns 300
```

As you can see sizes are different: ***304 bytes vs 300 bytes***. I have read [this on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing) and [The Lost Ark of Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/#_alignment_requirements), but I cannot explain why there is such difference with *default padding/packing rules*.

Anyway I solved by setting the struct in this way (long var one place before):

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t componentType;                             // 4
    bool componentId_present;                           // 1 + 3 padding = 4
    long componentId;                                   // 8
    uint32_t componentIdType;                           // 4 + 0 padding = 4
    uint32_t componentConfigUpdate_type;                // 4 + 0 padding = 4
    bool componentConfigUpdate_s1AP_present;            // 1 + 3 padding = 4
    ....
} data_E2setupRequest_NodeComponentConfigUpdate_t;      // 256 + 8 + 8*4 = 256 + 8 + 32 = 296
```

and

```
import struct
size = struct.calcsize("i?lii?i128s?i128s")             # returns 296
```

Comment: On which architecture(s)? (32/64bit, endianness...)

Comment: I'm compiling from a little endian x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`struct` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment):

> Padding is only automatically added between successive structure members. No padding is added at the beginning or the end of the encoded struct.

You've miscalculated the padding for your C structure - assuming typical structure layout and 8-byte longs, `sizeof(data_E2setupRequest_NodeComponentConfigUpdate_t`) will be 304 rather than 300, but `componentConfigUpdate_s1AP_present` actually goes in the space you thought was padding after `componentConfigUpdate_type`. The extra 4 bytes of padding are actually at the end of the structure, and `struct` doesn't add that padding.

Also from the `struct` module docs:

> To align the end of a structure to the alignment requirement of a particular type, end the format with the code for that type with a repeat count of zero.

So if you want `struct` to pad the end of the structure to `long` alignment, you can add `0l` to the end of the format string.

(Also, `bool` is 1 byte, not 4 - there are 3 bytes of padding after all the bools in your struct. You could get rid of some of that padding by putting all the bools next to each other.)